# Deploying static webpack to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, webpack, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket

Facing a weird issue at the moment.

I have a app that I pack with webpack in my pipeline with the following command:
`./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.dev.js`

After that I package the /dist/ folder like this:
`- zip -r ../deployment-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip ./dist`

This .zip consists of webpacked fiels and my index.html which is the entry point!
And finally I deploy this .zip to the azure app service like this:

`- pipe: microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.0 variables: AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: "${webAppName}-test-rg" AZURE_APP_NAME: "${webAppName}-test" ZIP_FILE: "deployment-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip"`

Basically I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli

The deployment succeeds but when I try and go to the app service url it says there is no content. I think I have to somehow point the app service to the index.html? But I don't know how. I tested the same deploy with a hello world Express example and this works! So the pipeline deploy and packaging seems to work. When I manually open the index.html in the dist folder after webpacking, this also works. So I am guessing the app service doesn't know what file to open, but as I read it it should know automatically.

Any tips?

Edit: When I ssh into the server I can see my deployed files

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy to the APP service, you got to deploy the content of your Webpack's generated `dist` folder to the `/home/site/wwwroot/` folder and not the `dist` folder itself. (Try accessing your website like this: `https://<app-service-url>/dist/index.html`; it will work).

So, your site's index.html file should be `/home/site/wwwroot/index.html` instead of `/home/site/wwwroot/dist/index.html`.

Instead of zipping from the root of the project, zip from the `dist` as your current folder:

```bash
cd dist
zip -r ../deployment-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.zip ./*
cd ..
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#create-a-project-zip-package) clearly mention this:

> [IMPORTANT] When creating the ZIP package for deployment, don't include the root directory, but only the files and directories in it. If you download a GitHub repository as a ZIP file, you cannot deploy that file as-is to App Service. GitHub adds additional nested directories at the top level, which do not work with App Service.